# Running VB.NET script with mono on a raspberry pi

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, raspberry-pi, mono, raspbian

I am trying to run a vb.net script using mono on the latest version of raspbian. The script was originally written in visual studio and i just downloaded the entire folder on to my raspberry pi 3 from dropbox and tried to run the .exe file.

```
mono /home/pi/Downloads/ctof/bin/Debug/ctof.exe
```

And got met with:

```
Unhandled Exception:
    System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 
    'Microsoft.VisualBasic, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies.
    File name: 'Microsoft.VisualBasic, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
    [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualBasic, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies.
    File name: 'Microsoft.VisualBasic, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
```

does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: You need that DLL.

Comment: `...please go easy...` Rather than beg for leniency, why not read [ask] and take the [tour] and learn how the site works?

Comment: Mono does have quite limited VB support, http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/languages/visualbasic/ But sounds like your Raspbian installation does not have the bits.

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=6715 (Can't run VB app on Raspberry Pi forum page) Should answer what your problem is

Answer (score 0):

Use these codes and check. Worked for me :D

**http://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/#download-lin-raspbian**

(I used Raspbian- check under linux tab, then raspbian tab, Raspbian 9(for Stretch) or Raspbian 8 (for Jessie))

*Raspbian 9 (armhf)*

**sudo apt install apt-transport-https dirmngr**

**sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF**

**echo "deb https://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian stable-raspbianstretch main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-official-stable.list**

**sudo apt update**

*Raspbian 8 (armhf)*

**sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF**

**sudo apt install apt-transport-https**

**echo "deb https://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian stable-raspbianjessie main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-official-stable.list**

**sudo apt update**

*use line by line*

and then install mono

**sudo apt install mono-devel**

and finally for vb use this

**sudo apt-get install mono-vbnc**

for more info 
**https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=6715**

Good luck mate :)